# how can i get div id of my aspx form after submiting the form with target iframe on server side after submit?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

i have use iframe for the submit of the form in aspx page,
now i have one div outside the from and i use this div to display message if any 
server side error is come. but after submitting the form i have assign the message to this 
div, but cant see the text in the browser.

actually is there a different way to access that div when we use iframe ?

if yes then can you please give me the idea about the same ?

thanks in advance.
Manish

Answer (score 0):

Pass the name of the div in the URL of the iframe, that way you will know it inside the iframe.

Use javascript to set the div of the outside iframe with something like:

window.opener.getElementByID('divID').innerHTML = 'tada';

Comment: how can i access it in jquey ?

Comment: Something like: $("#divID", parent.document.body).value = 'tada';

Comment: BTW it should be lowercase 'd', getElementById('divID')